# How NamespaceManager and Query by key works together in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have two organisation in my datastore inside their own namespace. Lets say organisation1 present inside namespace1 and organisation2 present inside namespace2. I am retrieving organisation by its web-safe-key. lets say that web-safe-key of organisation1 is orgWebSafeKey1 and web-safe-key of organisation2 is orgWebSafeKey2. I am using following code to get an organisation:

```
NamespaceManager.set("namespace1");
Organisation organisation = (Organisation) ofy().load().key(Key.create(orgWebSafeKey1)).now();
```

above code works as I expected because organisation1 is present inside namespace1 and I am trying get that organisation in its namespace.

But if I just change the websafekey of the organisation then according to my expectaion below query should result "null" organisation because there is no organisation with key orgWebSafeKey2 inside namespace1. But practically it is giving me organisation2.

```
NamespaceManager.set("namespace1");
Organisation organisation = (Organisation) ofy().load().key(Key.create(orgWebSafeKey2)).now();
```

If the above query result is correct and expected according to objectify and datastore then can I assume that query by key works globally , across all the namespaces?
I also want confirmation that in this case Key.create(orgWebSafeKey2) will not change the namespace of the key? and query is running according to the namespace of the key not by NamespaceManager.set("namespace1")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Datastore Key contains the following components:

1. Project/App ID
2. Namespace
3. Entity Path (Ancestor Kind + ID/Name(zero or more), Final Entity Kind + ID/Name)

Since namespace is part of the key, lookup of an entity by Key always finds the right entity regardless of the namespace set by the NamespaceManager. In other words, a Key is a GUID that uniquely identifies an entity across all apps/projects.

Refer to the below link for more details/answers for your questions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore

Comment: so it means that " query by key works globally" ,Key.create(orgWebSafeKey2) will not change the namespace of the key and above query will run according to the namespace of key.@Sai

Comment: @Baqir - that is correct. Both points were proved with the sample code you have posted and the results you have got.